# Is there any way to extract all the info from a sabre queue?

Tags: sabre

Ive been copying all the accounting data from each pnr in a queue into a an excel file, but it feels like a massive waste of time. Is there any program that will extract all the info from a sabre queue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a platform to ask people to write your code, but a community that helps you with problems in your code. If you can show what you have tried to code so far and any errors you encountered we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Sabre product that will do this for you, you will have to develop your own or find a vendor that can extract data from Sabre for you.

If you can develop things on your own, you can achieve this with Sabre Web Services or a simple script application within Sabre Red using Sabre Scribe (or Qik, I think), but those products are too complicated to explain on Stack Overflow.

You can refer to the [Sabre Developer Center](https://developer.sabre.com/home) to view all of the available APIs and documentation.